# Skydrive has lost files

Tags: onedrive

I really wanted to trust it. A week or so ago I was working on a PowerShell script saved inside my SkyDrive Pro 'drive'. I returned today to work on it and it's gone. I have 2 different apps - the PowerShell ISE and SSMS both showing it in recent files - both unable 'to find' it. I have a couple other workstation - all at the same 8.1 level - all using the same 'Live' account and Office365.

Win8.1 - Office 365 - have been running the MSDN version of 8.1 since it's release -about a month- so the recent update is not coming into play.

Would very much like to see logs of Skydrive interactions - also like to see a utility to autobacks SD files in a non-delete fashion.

ADDENDUM: Some clarification on the SkyDrive folder in question. The missing file is from the Win8.1 native SkyDrive folder - not Office365's SkyDrive Pro. As far as I know there's no other interface on this folder - it's bound to a local path what would be the same on any workstation I use from my 'Microsoft' account. The lexical hoops we have to deal with is going to become a problem in this newly clouded world.

[image]
thx

Comment: Check your Skydrive recycle bin - on the Skydrive web page it's in the lower left corner.

Comment: Not seeing that on my Office365 (sm biz prem) SkyDrive - the left panel shows 'Recent Files'; a toggle link to More or Few; at the very left lower corner is 'Use Office OnDemand'.

Comment: Note your screenshot shows both SkyDrive Pro and SkyDrive which are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Can look in the SkyDrive recycle bin.

Not sure about the Office365 which provides SkyDrive Pro. The regular accessed through https://skydrive.live.com/ has the recycle bin in the lower left as shown below.

[image: picture of bottom left of logged in SkyDrive webpage]

Not very familiar with SkyDrive Pro which is actually a form of Sharepoint behind the scenes which by default blocks various file types. See: [Types of files that cannot be added to a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-HA101907868.aspx) Still for Sharepoint Online it doesn't block the various PowerShell script file types.